# How can I introduce vertex labels into a graph

Tags: version-7, combinatorica

How can I introduce vertex labels into a graph in Mathematica 7 with Combinatorica?

I create graphs with `Graph` or `GraphPlot`, but how can I set my own graph vertices in Mathematica 7?

Comment: Use the option `VertexLabel->True`, e.g, `ShowGraph[CompleteGraph[5], VertexLabel -> True]`?

Comment: But I have my own graphs created with Graph, e.g. by g=Graph[{1$\rightarrow$2,2$\rightarrow$3}]. How can I introduce the vertex Labels, e.g. 1$\rightarrow$"one"? The commands of higher versions of Mathematica or the respective commands don't work.

Comment: IV_, does `ShowGraph[SetGraphOptions[g, VertexLabel -> True]]` give what you need?

Comment: Use `->` as the operator, not some fancy arrow you copy-pasted off the Internet.

Comment: or `ShowGraph[SetGraphOptions[g, VertexLabel -> {"one", "two", ""}]]`?

Comment: The last works. But how does PlotGraph work here?

Comment: With `GraphPlot` you can use `GraphPlot[g, VertexLabeling -> True]`

Comment: SetGraphOptions[g, VertexLabel -> {"one", "two", ""}]], defined separately or as argument of a command, works only with ShowGraph, not with GraphPlot. How can I introduce the vertex labels into GraphPlot?